# c++ casting derived to void* and restoring base

Tags: c++, casting

I have:

```
class A {...};

class B : public A {...};

class C : public B {...};
```

Then I'm storing C instance as void*:

```
C *instance = new C();
void *pC = instance;
```

Is it ok to make this:

```
B *pB = reinterpret_cast<B*>(pC);
```

Or I have to cast to C* only?

PS: I have more classes derived from B in my program and I'm not sure if's ok to cast like i'm doing (to B*).

**Why void*:** I'm using `void *userdata' field` of physical body class in box2d engine. I can't store my class there in other way

Comment: `I can't store my class there in other way.` - are you sure? Usually, in C++, turning a plain class into a template allows using something like `T *userData` instead of `void *userData` (where `T` is the type on which the template is instantiated.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I'm using a Box2D phys engine which stores userData as void*. I don't think it's a good idea to modify the code of phys engine by myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest casting it back to the original `C*` then do a `dynamic_cast` to `B*` in order to follow the rules of C++ - although you should avoid casting to `void*` in the first place and instead use a base pointer (`A*`) instead of void ptr.

Comment: I can't avoid casting to void* because i'm storing my class as void* userdata field of another extern class

Comment: To be fair, a `void*` pointer can be a great type erasure help with a combination of function pointers and function templates. Though, you likely won't do that in usercode, rather in a library.

Comment: The proper cast `C* -> B*` here should be `static_cast`. `dynamic_cast` is for casting downwards in the inheritance tree. Casting to `C*` first is needed, as otherwise the code could break for multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Andrew I suspected as much, anyway try to avoid it. Once one strips away the type info (the little there is in C++) you sort of open up for all kinds of runtime issues if you are not careful.

Comment: @Xeo yes, if possible it is better to avoid it like goto. :-)

Comment: @filmor: I think it should say, "as otherwise it is UB", shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should be undefined, but on every compiler I know non-virtual single inheritance is (memorywise) equivalent to `struct Derived { Base base; … };`. I thought this might be a rule.

Answer (score 1):

For the code you shown it should be ok to cast directly to `B*` and you can use `static_cast` for this. However, in general, pointers to base and derived classes might be different and you'll have to cast to the original type first and only then cast it to the pointer to base.

**Edit:** that should be ok in practice for single inheritance, but in general it's UB.

Comment: How do you know that the conversion from `C*` to `B*` is a no-op? I don't believe that's mandated anywhere.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Agree, it does not seem to be mandated even for standard-layout classes. I edited the answer to make it more clear that it's UB even if it's how it is usually implemented.

Comment: I'd go the other way and say "It's UB, but sometimes the pointer to base is the same as the pointer to derived and you can get away with a reinterpret-cast"... though all this happens at compile time, so I'd say it's really poor advice to recommend something that might just sometimes have a chance of not being broken, when the correct solution is no harder.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that when you cast from a pointer to `void *` you should always cast back to the one you originally came from.

Casting to void* is sometimes a necessary evil because of old APIs.

And sometimes it is done by design to create a "light" template. A light template is where you write code that handles a collection of pointers to objects, which are all handled in the same way, and this prevents code having to be generated for every type.

Around this code you have a strongly typed template that does the simple thing of casting back and forth (likely to be inlined anyway) so the users get strongly typed code but the implementation is less bloated.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine. You'll only get access to methods of `A` and `B` in this case though. (You'll simply "hide" methods of `C`.)

Answer (score -1):

Casting to void* is always a bad idea and so is doing a dynamic_cast. If you have to, it mostly means your code requires re-factoring as it is an object design flaw.